# Plugin to convert JSON object from API to Highcharts format

Tags: highcharts

Is there a plugin that automatically converts the JSON object from the API response to an array object that Highcharts supports?

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts doesn't offer any official plugin which will do this. User has a possibility to set a lot of properties in the data object and this plugin could disturb it.
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Maybe you should consider using other options to attach your data: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro